# Creating Pivotviewer Collection

Tags: silverlight, collections, pivotviewer

I'm trying to create a JIT pivotviewer and I have been kinda struggling a bit.  Could someone clear my confusion on how the cxml is dynamically created?  Also how should the information be set up for me to request it?  I currently have it sitting inside of my database, do I need to create an xml doc for it to load from or can it pull it straight from the db?

Answer (score 0):

For building a **JIT PivotViewer collection** you start by downloading the [JIT example](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/pivotviewer/just-in-time-sample-code/) built by Microsoft.

Look around in the solution, when getting started the most important bit is the `CollectionFactories` project. To create a collection using data from your database you need to create your custom `CollectionFactory`.

Your custom collectionfactory extends the `CollectionFactoryBase` class:

```
class MyCustomCollection : CollectionFactoryBase
```

the class needs to implement the `MakeCollection` method, all this method has to do is create an instance of `Collection` class and add `CollectionItems` to it.

```
public override PivotServerTools.Collection MakeCollection(CollectionRequestContext context) {
    return MakeCollection();
}

private static PivotServerTools.Collection MakeCollection() {
        PivotServerTools.Collection collection = new PivotServerTools.Collection();
        collection.Name = "MyImages";
        ItemImage[] fileList = ImageListFromDatabase();

        foreach (ItemImage image in fileList) {
            collection.AddItem(image.Name, image.ImageUrl.ToString(), image.Description, image, null);
            }

        return collection;
    }
```

Now to use this collection and see it in action, you need to provide the `name of the collection` for the PivotViewer Silverlight application (`PivotServer`) in the solution:

**default.aspx**

```
<param name="initParams" value="cxml=MyImages.cxml" />
```

Comment: Definitely helped, thanks.  But now I'm running into a problem where my JIT doesn't load the images as images, they show up as a facet to query against and just displays the standard green box.  I've checked through the project but I couldn't really find how the cxml files are created in order to display the images.

Comment: I don't follow you, maybe you could post a screenshot? You see pivot collection, where instead of images you have boxes for each image?

Comment: Its showing what I assume is the default background when you don't supply an image. [link]https://skydrive.live.com/?wa=wsignin1.0&cid=637c712fa84d9985&sc=photos#!/?cid=637C712FA84D9985&id=637C712FA84D9985!106&sc=photos!cid=637C712FA84D9985&id=637C712FA84D9985!107&sc=photos  and 
https://skydrive.live.com/?wa=wsignin1.0&cid=637c712fa84d9985&sc=photos#!/?cid=637C712FA84D9985&id=637C712FA84D9985!106&sc=photos are two images of what I'm describing

Comment: Check and recheck your image paths.

Comment: How should I configure the image paths?  Currently I have them set inside the server, the link isn't set as a URL but I'm not entirely sure that is how it's supposed to be set up.